# In MLR, How to set Logical Hyperparameter to either TRUE or FALSE only?

Tags: r, hyperparameters, mlr

I have this dataset to try to make a classification task using classif.ada

```
library(mlr)
data("HouseVotes84")
#Using HouseVotes84 as Classification Task Dataset and mtcars as Regression Task Dataset
dummy_data_classif <- HouseVotes84[,2:length(colnames(HouseVotes84))] %>% 
  mutate_if(is.factor, as.numeric)
dummy_data_classif <- data.frame(cbind(Class=HouseVotes84[,1], dummy_data_classif))
dummy_data_classif[is.na(dummy_data_classif)] <- 0
dummy_data_classif_numeric <- dummy_data_classif[-1] %>%
  mutate_if(is.factor, as.numeric)
dummy_data_classif_numeric <- data.frame(cbind(dummy_data_classif[1], 
                                               dummy_data_classif_numeric))
colnames(dummy_data_classif_numeric) <- colnames(dummy_data_classif)
```

and I have this parameter expression in string that will be evaluate later for classif.ada param set in MLR

```
param_to_eval

"hyperparam <<- makeParamSet(
makeIntegerParam(\"iter\",lower = 50,upper=250), 
makeIntegerParam(\"max.iter\",lower = 30,upper=200), 
makeLogicalParam(\"model.coef\",FALSE, tunable=FALSE), 
makeDiscreteParam(\"loss\",values = c(\"exponential\", \"logistic\")), 
makeDiscreteParam(\"type\",values = c(\"discrete\", \"real\", \"gentle\")), 
makeNumericParam(\"nu\",lower = 0,upper=100), 
makeNumericParam(\"bag.frac\",lower = 0,upper=1), 
makeLogicalParam(\"bag.shift\"), 
makeNumericParam(\"delta\",lower = 0,upper=1e-07), 
makeIntegerParam(\"minsplit\",lower = 1,upper=30), 
makeIntegerParam(\"minbucket\",lower = 1,upper=20), 
makeNumericParam(\"cp\",lower = 0,upper=1), 
makeIntegerParam(\"maxcompete\",lower = 0,upper=6), 
makeIntegerParam(\"maxsurrogate\",lower = 0,upper=7.5), 
makeDiscreteParam(\"usesurrogate\",values = c(0, 1, 2)), 
makeDiscreteParam(\"surrogatestyle\",values = c(0, 1)), 
makeIntegerParam(\"maxdepth\",lower = 1,upper=30))"
```

Then I defined tasking for classif.ada, and planned for tuning 20 random param sets

```
task <- makeClassifTask(data = dummy_data_classif_numeric, 
                        target = "Class")
lrn <- makeLearner(cl = "classif.ada", fix.factors.prediction = TRUE)
eval(parse(text=param_to_eval)) 

hyper_search <- makeTuneControlRandom(maxit = 20)
resampling_method <- makeResampleDesc("cv")
    
# Perform tuning
lrn_tune <- tuneParams(learner = "classif.ada", task = task, 
                       resampling = resampling_method, 
                       control = hyper_search, par.set = hyperparam)
```

In these examples, I want the `"model.coef"` hyperparameter to only contain `FALSE` value to tune, After running these, `model.coef` is still tuned between `TRUE` and `FALSE` and getting this error:

```
[Tune] Started tuning learner classif.ada for parameter set:
                   Type len   Def               Constr Req Tunable Trafo
iter            integer   -     -            50 to 250   -    TRUE     -
max.iter        integer   -     -            30 to 200   -    TRUE     -
model.coef      logical   - FALSE                    -   -   FALSE     -
loss           discrete   -     - exponential,logistic   -    TRUE     -
type           discrete   -     - discrete,real,gentle   -    TRUE     -
nu              numeric   -     -             0 to 100   -    TRUE     -
bag.frac        numeric   -     -               0 to 1   -    TRUE     -
bag.shift       logical   -     -                    -   -    TRUE     -
delta           numeric   -     -           0 to 1e-07   -    TRUE     -
minsplit        integer   -     -              1 to 30   -    TRUE     -
minbucket       integer   -     -              1 to 20   -    TRUE     -
cp              numeric   -     -               0 to 1   -    TRUE     -
maxcompete      integer   -     -               0 to 6   -    TRUE     -
maxsurrogate    integer   -     -             0 to 7.5   -    TRUE     -
usesurrogate   discrete   -     -                0,1,2   -    TRUE     -
surrogatestyle discrete   -     -                  0,1   -    TRUE     -
maxdepth        integer   -     -              1 to 30   -    TRUE     -
With control class: TuneControlRandom
Imputation value: 1
[Tune-x] 1: iter=233; max.iter=141; model.coef=FALSE; loss=exponential; type=gentle; nu=63.5; bag.frac=0.686; bag.shift=TRUE; delta=3.49e-08; minsplit=21; minbucket=2; cp=0.881; maxcompete=1; maxsurrogate=2; usesurrogate=2; surrogatestyle=0; maxdepth=17
[Tune-y] 1: mmce.test.mean=0.0598309; time: 0.8 min
[Tune-x] 2: iter=230; max.iter=115; model.coef=TRUE; loss=exponential; type=gentle; nu=39.6; bag.frac=0.35; bag.shift=TRUE; delta=4.87e-08; minsplit=1; minbucket=2; cp=0.523; maxcompete=4; maxsurrogate=7; usesurrogate=0; surrogatestyle=1; maxdepth=21
Error in if (any(wt < 0)) stop("negative weights not allowed") : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning message:
In log((1 - errm)/errm) :
 Error in if (any(wt < 0)) stop("negative weights not allowed") : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

How to make `"model.coef"` contain `FALSE` only?

Comment: First, the line where you define `lrn <-` does not run because the object `method` is not defined. Also, you don't actually use the `lrn` object later on.
Second, why do you parse the `ParamSet` definition? Why don't you store it directly as an object?

Comment: sorry the method is actually classif.ada, I use parse, since the result of the string paramset is from a built-in function :), later need it to dynamically make param sets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want one value to be fixed and not included in the search space you have to set the value of this parameter manually and exclude it form the search space:

```
hyperparam$pars$model.coef = NULL
learner <- makeLearner("classif.ada", par.vals = list(model.coef = FALSE))
lrn_tune <- tuneParams(learner = learner, task = task, 
                       resampling = resampling_method, 
                       control = hyper_search, par.set = hyperparam)
```

It makes more sense to leave out `model.coef` in the definition of the search space (`hyperparam` object) directly, but your example looks like you somehow  have the object predefined.

Comment: I tried to leave out the model.coef from the search space earlier but since the default value is TRUE, it will make the tune fail for some reason if it were TRUE, so I may need to changed it directly :)

Answer (score 1):

To create a fixed param for a learner set it in `par.vals` when creating the learner. See https://mlr.mlr-org.com/reference/makeLearner.html.

Params specified in the a ParamSet will always be tuned across the specified range.

PS: Assigning a ParamSet to the GlobalEnv using `<<-` is not a good idea (in general, not just for mlr).
PS2: Note that {mlr} is deprecated and {mlr3} should be used instead.